# testing components with external template (angularjs >= 1.5)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'd like to test a component with an external template. But whenever I try to find an element in a component , I get no results whatsoever. It looks as if the component was empty.

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm loading the templates or am I compiling the component correctly??

**project structure:**

```
libs/
app/
    arc/
        app.component.js
        app.module.js
        feature1/
            A.component.js
            A.component.spec.js
            A.controller.js
            A.html
        feature2/
            B.component.js
            B.component.spec.js
            B.controller.js
            B.html
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
//jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './src/app',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      '../../libs/angular/angular.js',
      '../../libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      '../../libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      '../../libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      '../../libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      '**/*.module.js',
      '**/*.spec.js',
      '**/*.html',
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
      '**/!(*.mock|*.spec).js': ['coverage']
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      // strip this from the file path
      ///stripPrefix: '',
      cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {
        let cacheId = filepath.split('/');
        return cacheId[ cacheId.length - 1 ];
      },
      // create a single module that contains templates from all the files
      moduleName: 'templates'
    },

    colors: true,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    reporters: ["spec"],

    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,             // limit number of lines logged per test 
      suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary 
      suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests 
      suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests 
      suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests 
      showSpecTiming: false,      // print the time elapsed for each spec 
      failFast: true              // test would finish with error when a first fail occurs.  
    }

  });
};
```

**A.html**

```
<header> test </header>
```

**A.component.js**

```
var AComponent = {
  templateUrl: './A.html',
  controller: 'AController',
  bindings: {
  }
};

angular
  .module('app')
  .component('feature1', AComponent );
```

**A.component.spec.js**

```
'use strict';

describe('Component: AComponent', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  var element;
  var component;
  var scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<feature1> </feature1>');
    scope.$apply(function(){
      $compile(element)(scope);
    });
  }));

  it('should contain header element', function() {
    console.log( element.find('header').length )
  });

});
```

Comment: `</feature1s>` remove the last `s` to match the open tag

Comment: ahh my bad, that was just a typo . But not really a root cause.

Comment: I don't see any element containing class `stat` so `element.find('.stat')` will find nothing

Comment: apologies, this is just a simplified version of my app. So I had to change few things to keep the example simple. The thing is that I can even see the template being loaded in `$templateCache`. But for some reason the template isn't rendered as part of the compile process.

Comment: @Alexus Is `templateUrl` in `$templateCache` the same as in component definition?

Comment: you were right, with the templateUrl . It seems that the name has to be completely accurate as it's defined in the component. Had to add the leading './' to all results of the `cacheIdFromPath` method .

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @StanislavKvitash, the `templateUrl` has to be exactly the same as defined in the component. In my case the leading './' was causing that the template couldn't be resolved while compiling the component.

In order to fix this, I've just added the missing './' to all results in  `cacheIdFromPath` method.

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    cacheIdFromPath: function(htmlPath) {
      let cacheId = htmlPath.split('/');
      return './'+cacheId[ cacheId.length - 1 ];
    },
    // create a single module that contains templates from all the files
    moduleName: 'templates'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I may have a temporary solution.

The thing is, I can actually all see the templates are being loaded correctly by checking the `$templateCache`. However their're not being picked up as part of the compile process. So in order to make it work, I had to explicitly set the template for the `$compile()` method.

The main problem here here is that when the template name changes, I'm gonna  have to update the spec files as well.

```
'use strict';

describe('Component: AComponent', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(module('templates'));

  var element;
  var scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache ){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    let template =  $templateCache.get('A.html');
    element = angular.element( '<feature1>'+template+'</feature1>' );
    scope.$apply(function(){
      $compile(element)(scope);
    });
  }));

  it('should contain header element', function() {
   var header = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('header'));
    expect(header.length).not.toBe(0);
  });

});
```